# Ignore specific html class in preg_match_all

Tags: php, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I am trying to preg_match_all  tags to do specific stuff to them, however, there is one type of  that I want to ignore the preg_match_all. I thought about giving the img a class so  and for the preg_match_all to ignore all imgs with the class "ignored".

In other words, do a preg_Match_all and if you find the word "ignored", skip it.

my code so far is:

```
preg_match_all( '/<img\s+.*?>/', $content, $matches );
```

but that detecs all img, I'm stuck on how to ignore ones with the word "ignored" in it.

Hopefully someone can give me a hand, thanks guys.

Comment: [Use a DOM Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).

Comment: or try [`xpath_match_all`](https://gist.github.com/1358174) with `//img[not(contains(@class, "ignored"))]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<img src="path_to_image0"><img src="path_to_image1" class="ignored">';

preg_match_all("/<img(.*|!ignored)>/",$str,$matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[1]);
echo '</pre>';
```