# Regular expressions, how to get all that is between tags?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

how can you get all that is between the tags: `<td class="detail"></td>` ? I use PHP.

Comment: Usually, parsing html with regex is not encouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . Your situation might be really specific and it might be acceptable, though.

Comment: good luck getting `/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>/` to work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)?

```
    $xpath = new DOMXPath(yourHtml);
    $nodeList = $xpath->query( "//td[@class='detail']" );
    foreach($nodeList as $node)
    {
      echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
```

Parsing HTML with regex isn't a good choice