# PHP Help REGEX / Explanation

Tags: php, regex, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

```
<td class="lbs" colspan="4">
    <span>4 Pack.</span>
    <span>
        <span class="strike">20.5</span>
        <span class="lbs">9.5</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Hey guys! I need some help. I've tried my best searching for an answer but i seem to have hit a wall.

I'm using curl to grab the piece of code from multiple pages above.

I'm trying to grab each of the values e.g. "4 pack., 20.5, 9.5" and assign them to a variable so i can pass them to a db.

Comment: This looks like a job for `DOMDocument`

Comment: Use DomDocument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and if you want to make lookups easy, DOMXPath.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Yep. DomDocument. This is definitely *not* a job for regex.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: @Gordon: Not really.  That question deals specifically with grabbing attributes from HTML tags.  This one deals with getting the contents of a given tag.  Though I agree with the other commenters that this is not a job for regex.

Comment: @Gordon: I'm not disputing that, I guess you and I just fall on different sides of this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123976/change-wording-of-exact-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
preg_match_all('@<td class="lbs" colspan="4">\s*<span>([^<]+)</span>\s*<span>\s*<span class="strike">([0-9\.]+)</span>\s*<span class="lbs">([0-9\.]+)</span>\s*</span>\s*</td>@ims', $source, $matches);
```

Comment: That works for today, with that exact piece of HTML.  It will break when `<td class="lbs" colspan="4">` becomes `<td colspan="4" class="lbs">` or `<td id="foo" class="lbs">` or maybe the `colspan` disappears.  You can't rely on the textual layout of HTML.  That's why you use DOMDocument or another HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really HAVE to use regex?

You have structured data, so just read the DOM.

If you **MUST** use regex try this:

```
@<[^>]+>[\n\r ]*([^<>\n]+)</[^>]+>@
```

EDIT

Usage:

```
$results = array();
preg_match_all(
  '@<[^>]+>[\n\r ]*([^<>\n]+)</[^>]+>@',
   $data, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
);
```