# Search all the content of an href in a chain php

Tags: php, regex, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

how can i find the values of all the href in a characters chain.

Example :

```
<a href = "blabla1"> Test1 </a>
<a href = "blabla2"> Test1 </a>
```

I want to retrieve blabla1 and blabla2.

I tried regular expression but I give up ! XD

Thanks

Comment: That's your problem: don't use regexes for DOM manipulation. It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php DOM

```
$str = <<<H
<a href="blabla1">Test1</a>
<a href="blabla2">Test1</a>
H;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $node){
    echo $node->getAttribute("href") . "<br>";
}
```

Here is documentation of [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: I dont know why, its not working ..

Comment: @Hulk It's working , what are you doing exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

XPath can do the job of getting the value of the attribute with `$xpath->query("//a/@value");`. Then you can iterate over the node list of attribute nodes and access the $value property of each attribute node.

Comment: Can you show an example please.