# Scraping a website when the body or row has no attributes?

Tags: php, html

I am new to coding and new to this website, so please go easy on me.

I have some code which is used to scrape a website, gather data, and place it into a MySQL database.  It works well.

I am now trying to tweak the code so it can scrape another website, however it doesn't have any class or id attributes for the `<tbody>` or `<tr>` tags, unlike the 1st website.

Example: (this is what I have available to work with) ...

```
<table class="tabledata">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="data1">123</td>
   <td class="data2">456</td>
   <td class="data3">789</td>
   <td class="data4">abc</td>
   <td class="data5">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="data1">987</td>
   <td class="data2">654</td>
   <td class="data3">321</td>
   <td class="data4">uvw</td>
   <td class="data5">xyz</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it still possible to the data from each of the  cells?

Many thanks.

MORE INFORMATION:

I won't know the data in each cell as it is constantly changing. Although I have only listed 2 rows in the question above, there are actually dozens of rows.

This is just part of the code that I've been trying:

```
    $d1s = $dom->find("table[class='tabledata']//tr");
$ord = 1;
foreach($d1s as $d1){
    //echo $d1->plaintext;
    //$d1->dump_node(true);
```

Comment: of course it's possible

Comment: Sorry, perhaps that wasn't a great question to ask.

Can anyone please suggest a way of being able to obtain the data from the cells in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by DOMXPATH class.

```
$html = your table path

$document = new DOMDocument();

$document->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($document);

$results = $selector->query('//td/a[text()="the name"]/..');



foreach($results as $node) {
echo $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771266/use-php-simple-html-dom-parser-to-find-table-cell-and-get-contents-of-next-sibli)

Comment: what do meta tags have to do with parsing table cells?

Comment: @charlietfl sorry i mis understood ops question ..now fixed it ..:) SEEMS LIKE this is he wanted