# PHP: How to replace only one line using a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
<li id="1">3431233</li>
<li id="2">fsdfdsfsdfdsfdsf</li>
<li id="3">abc</li>
<li id="4"> fdsf2342343</li>
<li id="5">123</li>
```

I want to replace only those lines containing abc or 123 with nothing (3rd and 5th in this case). My problem is that this regex wont work:

```
^<li>abc<\/li>
```

It replaces all lis. How can I only limit the replaceing to one certain line? The li differ from line to line and thats dynamic, I do not know how they will look (what classes and ids they might have.)

Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie: With "nothing".

Comment: Whats the pattern for the lines that you want removed? Is it the length of 3 chars?

Comment: See the Accepted Answer in the dupe. Instead of loadXML() and saveXML() you use loadHTML() and saveHTML() respectively. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml/3577662#3577662 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783 for more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [**here**](http://regexpal.com/)

```
^<li id="[0-9]">(abc|123|)<\/li>
```

Use `[0-9]+` if id grows

```
^<li id="[0-9]+">(abc|123|)<\/li>
```

Comment: +1 @HamZaDzCyberDeV for your tip...

Comment: @Wazzzy you need to have `abc|123|` to account for the case where the inner content is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
^<li>(abc|123|)<\/li>
```

I tested it [here](http://www.regextester.com/) and it worked

Comment: I edited my post ... please have a look again

Answer (score 2):

simply use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php
  str_replace("<li>abc</li>"," ", $yourstring);
  str_replace("<li>123</li>"," ", $yourstring);
```

**EDIT :** try this:

```
    '/<li(.*)>(abc|123)<\/li>/';
```

Comment: make it ungreedy `.*?` and maybe add optional spaces ? `'/<li(.*?)>\s*(abc|123)\s*<\/li>/'`