# Get value of href in php

Tags: php, jquery

So I have this code:

`<a style="color:white" id="randomNo">Hello</a>;`

I am using jQuery to get the value of it by using:

`$('#randomNo').text();`

Is there a way to get the value ("Hello") in PHP?

Comment: Is the code part of an `HTML` page or is it generated by `PHP`? Is it a `PHP` string?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan the code is part of an html page sir.

Comment: As `PHP` only works server-side (not client-side), there would not be a way to retroactively process this data with `PHP`.

Comment: u can use ajax for that.

Comment: So, are you just looking to find the contents of an `a` tag from a set of HTML code (most likely from something like `file_get_contents(...)`)?

Comment: @HassanAli do you have a sample code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element
Here you go

Comment: @Mic I think he's trying to get the contents of the tag, not the `href`.

Answer (score 1):

@FewFlyBy here look (Note: this is just a example of using js var in php).

```
<div id="foo">Click Me</div>    
    $("#foo").on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var randomNo= $('#randomNo').text();
        // Ajax.
        $.ajax({
            url: "SAMPLE.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                   randomNo: randomNo
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
```

on `SAMPLE.php` get the value from `$_POST['randomNo'];`

This is just a sample. if want want you can send your value to php page like above.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You have to extract the anchor tag then textContent will help you to fetch the text of anchor tag

Here is the sample stuff

```
$link = "<a href='test.php'>tester</a>";
$dom = new domdocument;
$dom->loadHTML($link);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
    echo $a->textContent, "\n";
    echo $a->getAttribute("href"), "\n";
}
```

Hope it helps.