# How can i get text from Tags?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have some question.How can i get text between tags in html??

```
<ReviewsClientModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.OneStore.Site.Models">
<Items>
<ReviewsClientModel.ReviewClientModel>
<HelpfulNegative>0</HelpfulNegative>
<HelpfulPositive>2</HelpfulPositive>
<IsPublished>true</IsPublished>
<IsTakenDown>false</IsTakenDown>
<Rating xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.OneStore.Site.Models.ViewModels">
<ReviewId>5ce5dc85-466d-a1cc-efe7-70bdd5183dfb</ReviewId>
<ReviewText>I downloaded this app it had someone in his eyes its kinda black so I don't know who it is.my cousin thinks its not scary but I get creeped out wen I saw him myself. Whoevers not scared then just wow just wow. FOR SAFETY DONT DOWNLOAD</ReviewText>
<SubmittedDateTime>2015-06-25T20:13:05.633</SubmittedDateTime>
<Title>FOR SAFETY DON"T PLAY</Title>
<UserId>985157380267961</UserId>
<UserName>natalie</UserName>
<ViolationsFound>false</ViolationsFound>
</ReviewsClientModel.ReviewClientModel>
```

For example I would like get "5ce5dc85-466d-a1cc-efe7-70bdd5183dfb". 
I tried that :

```
public function getXpath($str)
    {
        \DB::connection('mongodb')->disableQueryLog();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $str = str_replace("\0", '', $str);
        $dom = new \DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $str);
        return new \DomXPath($dom);
    }
$xpath = $this->getXpath($str);
$tmpCommId = $xpath->query("//ReviewId");
             $comm_id = trim($tmpCommId->item($j)->nodeValue);
```

I used Curl to download Web Site,and i saved in $str.

Comment: Ok i know how i should do it. I did it that ,after i used Curl ,$str=json_decode($str,true); ,and i will get array with where key=tag name,and value=text from between tags.

Comment: Your question says "in HTML", but your example shows XML. Do you mean XML?

Comment: Yes i mean XML ,my friend told me about diffrence HTML and XML ,and I know now i should use other tools. Anyway thanks for answers.

Comment: First, you probably want to use [LoadXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) rather than LoadHTML, since it's XML you want to process. Secondly, what happened when you tried the code that you showed? And what is the value of `$j`? Maybe you want `->item(0)` instead of using `$j`?


  [1]:

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you are still having a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is assuming you want to use Javascript.

You can parse html using [Pure JavaScript HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/).

Check that blog for documentation on the library. Might be a little outdated.

EDIT:

LarsH informed me that you wanted an XML scraper in PHP. Although I should have checked your sample code to actually check what it was, it would really help to remind people what you want it in.

As for the answer, whicle I'm not very familiar with php, [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) should be able to handle this pretty well.

In addition, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783) is a SO answer from the past that is a pretty good example of using DOM to parse HTML. Should be easy enough to use it with XML instead. Hope that helps.

Comment: It turns out that he wants to parse XML rather than HTML. Does this answer still work? Also, he seems to be using PHP.

Comment: @LarsH Yeah, I didn't notice that he wanted to use XML. Updating my answer now. Thanks for letting me know.