# combine two different regex patterns

Tags: php, regex

I'm using curl to extract data from a website and i want to get content of a specific `<span>`. it worked perfectly with

```
$pattern4 = '/<span class=\"_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1\">(.*?)<\/span>/i';
$cc = preg_match_all($pattern4, $ccpage, $matches);

print_r($matches[1][0]);`
```

This return : `some text - digits`, in the original website they're separated by `<br />` i already have a pattern to only match the digits

`$pattern5 = "\s\d+\s(?=\-)"`

but i don't know how to combine them to get only the digits from that specific

`<span class="_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1">`

Comment: get digits from `<span>`?  can you show your html input that shows the content of the span

Comment: I used [dom-crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) component for crawling websites.

Comment: @sweaver2112 <span class="_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1">Name<br /> 713286XXX971 - 12021980</span>

Comment: i see it now...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
<span class=\"_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1\">.*?([\dX]+).*?<\/span>
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/enPOdC/1/)

another (possibly safer) pattern that would use the `<br/>` tag to avoid matching too early (say if the text has a number in it):

```
<span class=\"_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1\">.*?<br\s?\/>\s([\dX]+).*?<\/span>
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LUCXn1/2/)

Comment: great one but i need to capture only 713286XXX971

Comment: yes i want to capture the whole number with X

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to scrap HTML, see [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element) as an example and here is a solution for your problem:

```
<?php
$html = '<html><head></head><body><span class="_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1">some text - 128</span></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$textContent = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $node) {
    if ($node->getAttribute('class') == '_c1 ei_card_subtitle _c1') {
        $textContent = $node->textContent;
        break;
    }
}
if ($textContent) {
    $pattern = '/\d+/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $textContent, $matches)) {
        var_dump($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: oblig: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: too much code to extract a simple set of numbers i prefer regex

Comment: Hi, agreed with that some times too, if your HTML is short it may be too much, but you can consider it for longer HTML since and it may be a safer method whenever the HTML change with time, but in my opinion the regexp may be fine too :)