# simple html php dom parser a way to gather information from all pages?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I wanted to know if its possible to make this code search every page from that website so it pulls every image src from all pages. Currently it will only pull the image src from that one page. I tried using a while loop but it only repeats the same results from the main page over and over.  Any help would be great.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

//show errors
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$html = file_get_html('http://betatv.net/');
$result=($html);
while($html = ($result)) {

// find the show img and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.entry-content') as $cover_img)
foreach($cover_img->find('img') as $cover_img_link)

//echo the images src
echo $cover_img_link->src .'<br>';
echo '<br>';

}
// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

?>
```

Proof that i own betatv.net i added a link to this question on the front page.

Comment: Do you won http://betatv.net ? If not, you probably should not be doing that; and you would need an ver sophisticated script to do this on a server you don't own. If you do, please update your question to say so (the script needed to do what you're asking would be much similar if you "own" the server).

Comment: Yes i own the betatv.net.

Comment: i added a link to this question on the front page as proof.

Comment: Anyone? Could really use some help with this.

Comment: I'm working on a solution to another user's question at the moment, but to get you started in the right direction, look at PHP's glob function (php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). you will need to open each text file and pass it into your script above. Also, consider that it is the wee-hours of the morning for North America and Europe right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice example of a page crawler:

[How do I make a simple crawler in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313107/how-do-i-make-a-simple-crawler-in-php)

You just need to use your piece of code for each link it finds.

Also if you own this page I bet there is a better way to find all images instead of crawling it from frontend.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out. I know i could get the links much easier but im experimenting with php for learning purpose. Its funny to cause i used that same link to find my answer only i found it from google. Next time i will make sure to do more searches before asking a new question.