# Crawl specific information from a webpage

Tags: php, web-crawler

http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Nikla

In this link, at the bottom of the character profile, there is a list of deaths.
How can I "collect" the date information?  I'm not worried about the rest, just the date of each death.

I will be using a PHP file to complete this.

I've seen this post: [How do I make a simple crawler in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313107/how-do-i-make-a-simple-crawler-in-php)
I just don't know where to begin.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DOM parse like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Download the archive from SourceForge install it, [`include`](http://php.net/include) the file in your script and then use it.

The website has an ugly table layout but you can do something like this:

**Code:**

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Nikla');
$count = 0; //counter variable
foreach($html->find('//*[@id="characters"]/div[5]/div/div/table[3]/tbody/tr['.
  $i.']') as $table) { //traverse through the table and get <td> content
   echo $table."<br/>";
   $count++;
}

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Character Deaths
Jul 11 2013, 08:08:11 CEST  Killed at Level 36 by Cintyus and Seque Ladinho.
Jul 11 2013, 07:32:31 CEST  Killed at Level 36 by Drunk Noongah and Rea Per.
Jul 09 2013, 22:05:42 CEST  Killed at Level 35 by Evil Kris and Tensser.
Jun 29 2013, 20:25:27 CEST  Killed at Level 27 by Knight Abron.
Jun 27 2013, 07:31:33 CEST  Killed at Level 23 by Mysterioz Pandoria Knight.
Jun 14 2013, 23:52:14 CEST  Died at Level 16 by a rotworm.
```

That's just an example to get you started. You can modify it and get what you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked well, I can definitely change it up to get what I need.