# T_STRING error in my php code

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have this PHP that is supposed to crawl End Clothing website for product IDs

When I run it its gives me this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'i' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\end3.php on line 5

```
<?php
#!/bin/bash
#Crawl End Clothing For Product IDs

for i in $(eval echo {$1..$2})
do
rm -f end-cookie.jar
curl -c end-cookie.jar -L 
http://www.endclothing.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lbmRjbG90aGluZy5jby51ay9ldHEtaGlnaC10b3AtMS1zbmVha2VyLWVuZC1leGNsdXNpdmUtZXRxLTQtZW5kYmsuaHRtbA,,/product/253361/form_key/DcwmUqDsjy4Wj4Az/ 

-s -o /dev/null
url='curl -b end-cookie.jar -w "%{url_effective}\n" -L -s -S -o 

/dev/null 
http://www.endclothing.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lbmRjbG90aGluZy5jby51ay9ldHEtaGlnaC10b3AtMS1zbmVha2VyLWVuZC1leGNsdXNpdmUtZXRxLTQtZW5kYmsuaHRtbA,,/product/

$i/form_key/DcwmUqDsjy4Wj4Az/ 
'
echo $i - $url
done
?>
```

How do I fix this please? Thanks

Comment: Can you really put an arbitrary shell script in `<?php` tags like that? That's news to me....

Comment: for i should be for $i. However I agree with the previous 2 people: What did you paste here?

Comment: sorry the long url looks odd I dont know why

Comment: I changed the i to $i and I'm still getting an error :(

Comment: It's a different error. You aren't writing PHP here, this looks like a shell script. Here's how a curl would be written in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you get this code of C# or C++ or other similar language, this code not work in PHP,

If you get an external java application (jar) use the exec functions instead.

```
$url_effective = "http://www.endclothing.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lbmRjbG90aGluZy5jby51ay9ldHEtaGlnaC10b3AtMS1zbmVha2VyLWVuZC1leGNsdXNpdmUtZXRxLTQtZW5kYmsuaHRtbA,,/product/$i/form_key/DcwmUqDsjy4Wj4Az/";
$crwal = exec("end-cookie.jar -w".$url_effective." -L -s -S -o");
```

Or some for this style.

Comment: yes I got it from an outside source and wasnt sure. I tried your advice and still gives me an error about line 5 :(

Comment: in php for bucle should be:

`for($i=0;$i <= $total_ids ; ++$i){ `. 

`$total_ids` is a fake variable, you should find a way to know the total of the data to run the for bucle, then put this in one variable.

Comment: This question can be very useful for your pourpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313107/how-do-i-make-a-simple-crawler-in-php?rq=1