# Stream a video file with variable name using php

Tags: php, html, stream

This is my html

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" width="640" height="480">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
        <source src="/projects/moviestream/php/stream.php">
    </video>
</div>
```

and my stream.php

```
// class definition of video_stream
$stream = new VideoStream($video_link);
$stream->start();
```

My question is how to pass the variable $video_link from my html to the php page so it streams the correct video?

Comment: you can send it through javascript by making an ajax call.

Comment: you can curl the page and then pass the page content. refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313107/how-do-i-make-a-simple-crawler-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using just plain php!
I use a kind of php router that allows me to route `movie/1` to VideoStreamer and invoking the method stream($id) wwith $id set to 1